# Excel: 100% Stack Bar Chart, the bars are not plotting correct for few combination of values

Tags: excel, charts, ms-office, excel-charts

Please look at the image below: How can orange bar in the first chart be that big. This pattern repeats even if I make both values half like 105, 21 or 53, 10 etc.

[image]

As soon as value is value is 43 the chart starts behaving fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel is changing the axis (that you don't have displayed) automatically to what it thinks is a relevant range.  However, this range is probably something like **75% to 100%** as in the following picture (with the axis displayed):

[image]

While this seems to not make sense for the purpose of a 100% stacked bar chart, this is nonetheless what Excel tries to do.

To fix it, go to Primary Horizontal Axis options and change the **Minimum** from "Auto" to "Fixed" and set the value to 0.  You might also want to set the **Maximum** to "Fixed" and set the value to 1.  See options pictured below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, If I just move the small value on top the chart starts working fine. Other thing I noticed is that if the top value is divided by the values below and the result is greater than equal to 5 the bar starts from 75% instead of 0% for example put 4 on top cell and 1 on bottom its fine now just change the value of top cell to 5 and chart bar is wrong.

Comment: @Kashif You're welcome.  I don't know why Excel chooses the axis ranges that it does (sometimes it's helpful, sometimes it's not).  It makes sense to me that a 100% stacked bar would *really* need to have the proportions shown correctly, but alas...

Answer (score 0):

Excel seems to start doing its auto axis adjustment once one of the numbers is less than about 20% of the other number.